# Do I need to specify pages when citing a book?

Tags: citations, citation-style, bibtex

I am citing the book Statistical Power Analysis for the behavioral sciences from pages 77 to 81. It seems @book in bibtex has no option for pages though. (I know I can use @inbook but if pages information is so necessary then why it is not included in @book?)

Comment: Have you tried using \cite[p.~77--81]{bookhandle}?

Comment: The title asks if citing pages is necessary, the question rather focuses on how to include pages in bibtex - in case of which this question would be a better fit in LaTeX SE. Please clarify what you want to have answered.

Comment: @Sursula Basically I want to ask if it is necessary to include pages, for I don't want to waste too much time on bibtex if it is unnecessary.

Comment: If the book is very long and/or challenging, it is very helpful to the reader to have a specific reference.

Comment: Oh I love it when I read "The claim now follows from [8]" in a math paper, while the authors actually mean "The claim now follows from a minor modification of Theorem 4.2.5 in the 600 pages book [8]. One just has to be careful that our space can be infinite dimensional, while it is assumed to be finite dimensional in the cited theorem - but we only use conclusion (iv) of the theorem, and a quick look at the three pages proof and the two preceding propositions (along with an easy application of Zorn's lemma) shows that (iv) also holds in infinite dimensions."

Comment: I agree with the comment of @JochenGlueck, but I'd add that I'm also unhappy about "the claim now follows from [8]" even if all the relevant information is explicitly and succinctly stated in the book [8]. The author ought to tell me where in [8] to look --- a page number, a section number, or a theorem number. I'm not going to search the whole book.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Yes indeed. I'd say the general point is that I expect the authors to include all information that is necessary to properly and smoothly understand their reference - including the theorem number (or page number, etc), of course. (But of course, one can achieve a nice "synergy effect" in stealing the readers' time by mentioning neither the theorem number nor the necessary modifications, to make sure that readers don't even know what precisely they are looking for in the 600 pages book.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing pages is rarely needed and better avoided in most cases, because page numbers may vary through book’s editions or even for reprints of the same edition.

You can cite the book section in the text, specifying the book edition in the bibliography. In LaTeX you can do this with

```
\cite[section~X]{Book}
```

And possibly check the publisher's style guide whether they want *section* capitalized or not.

Comment: Great answer, but I suggest to use a [capital S](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/9455/958) in "section".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It depends on the journal style: some journals (chiefly British) do not capitalize section, chapter. So, I leave to the reader the capitalization according to the journal style (I'll edit to specify). Personally, I find texts more readable with less capitals ;-)

Comment: American English is really obsessed with capital letters to make everything BIG

Comment: Instead of "section X," you could use `\S X` (in LaTeX).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I used to use that paragraph symbol in the past, but I discovered that many people is not familiar with that and asked about the meaning. So, since then, I prefer to write _section in full_. I think it's a pity because in the long run this cause an impoverishment of the symbols and the language.

Comment: I'd say if there is something more specific you use than a section, e.g. a theorem, it makes most sense to refer to the theorem number.

Comment: @user151413 Sure, but since the OP specified a range of 4 pages, I guessed that's probably a section rather than the statement of a theorem.

Comment: I see, I had chapters in mind (guess as you wrote Section X and not Section X.1). Sections do indeed also make sense if they are not too extensive.